# Why data wasn't saved when I use @Transactional annotation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactional

Colleagues, could you help me with `@Transactional` annotation. My aim is to pass DB transaction management to Spring and in current case save data in DB.

I have two methods in DAO class:

```
@Component
    public class OdValuesDAO
    {


           static final Logger LOG = 

Logger.getLogger(OdValuesDAO.class.getName());
        @Autowired
        // @PersistenceContext(unitName = "PersistenceUnit")
        @Qualifier("emR")
        private EntityManager em;
    public void addOdValue (OdValuesEntity odValuesEntity) {
        LOG.info(odValuesEntity.toString());
        //EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction(); Data will be saved DB if uncomment this code.
        ///tx.begin();
        //LOG.info(tx.isActive());
        em.persist(odValuesEntity);
        ///tx.commit();

    }


    public List<OdValuesEntity> getShare (OdValuesEntity odValuesEntity) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<OdValuesEntity> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(OdValuesEntity.class);
        Root<OdValuesEntity> entityRoot = criteriaQuery.from(OdValuesEntity.class);

        Predicate criteria = cb.conjunction();
        if (odValuesEntity.getId() != null) .........

        criteriaQuery.where(criteria);
        List<OdValuesEntity> result = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();

        return result;

    }
```

and service method:

```
    @Component
    public class OdValuesService {

        static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(OdValuesService.class.getName());

        @Autowired
        private OdValuesDAO odValuesDAO;

    /**
     * Read data from table.
     * @param odValuesEntity
     * @return
     */

    @Transactional (readOnly = true, value = "txtxManagerR")
    public List<OdValuesEntity> getShare (OdValuesEntity odValuesEntity) {
        odValuesDAO.getShare(odValuesEntity);
        return odValuesDAO.getShare(odValuesEntity);

    }
    /** Add record to the table
    */
    @Transactional (value = "txtxManagerR") /*I have two transaction managers for two different DataSources/
    public void addOdValue (OdValuesEntity odValuesEntity) {
        odValuesDAO.addOdValue(odValuesEntity);
    }

}
```

And I have a test which call these two methods. I can read data from the table using `getShare` method. But no data saved after calling method `addOdValue`. This is my problem.
When I uncomment transaction related code in `addOdValue` everything works fine. As I understood in this case Spring transaction manager doesn't work.

How to correct `addOdValue` method or, may be, spring config file to save data in the database (to open and commit transaction) using Spring @Transactional annotation?

My Spring config (context) contains next beans to work with DB:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource specRDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource specRDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        specRDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
        specRDataSource.setUrl(specRDbUrl);
        specRDataSource.setUsername(specRDbUser);
        specRDataSource.setPassword(specRDbPassword);
        specRDataSource.setMaxIdle(30);
        specRDataSource.setMaxWaitMillis(10000);
        specRDataSource.setValidationQuery("select 1 from rdb$database");
        specRDataSource.setTestOnBorrow(false);
        specRDataSource.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        specRDataSource.setDefaultAutoCommit(true);

        return specRDataSource;
    }



    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource bortDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource bortDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        bortDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        bortDataSource.setUrl(bortDbUrl);
        bortDataSource.setUsername(bortDbUser);
        bortDataSource.setPassword(bortDbPassword);
        bortDataSource.setMaxIdle(2);
        bortDataSource.setMaxWaitMillis(10000);
        bortDataSource.setValidationQuery("select 1");
        bortDataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        bortDataSource.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        bortDataSource.setDefaultAutoCommit(true);
        return bortDataSource;
    }



    @Bean
    public  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory (BasicDataSource bortDataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localConnectionFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        localConnectionFactoryBean.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml");
        localConnectionFactoryBean.setDataSource(bortDataSource);
        localConnectionFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        return localConnectionFactoryBean;
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactorySpec (BasicDataSource specRDataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml");
        emf.setDataSource(specRDataSource);
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect");
        emf.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter);

        return emf;
    }


    @Bean
    public EntityManager emR (@Qualifier("entityManagerFactorySpec") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactorySpec) {
        return entityManagerFactorySpec.createEntityManager();
    }


    @Bean
    public EntityManager embort (@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory ) {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }




    @Bean
    public  JpaTransactionManager txtxManagerR (@Qualifier("entityManagerFactorySpec") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactorySpec) {
         JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
         txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactorySpec);
         return txManager;
    }


    @Bean
    public  JpaTransactionManager txManagerbort (@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

My persistence.xml looks like (if need):

```
<persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.acap.app.JpaEntities.OdDocsEntity</class>
        <class>com.acap.app.JpaEntities.OdValuesEntity</class>
    .......
        <class>com.acap.app.JpaEntities.OdOSharesEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                      value="connection string"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password"/>
            <property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "false" />
           <property name = "hibernate.format_sql" value = "false" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
```

Stack trace doesn't show any error. Thank you for helping.

**UPDATE**
Test running:

```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
    public class OdValuesServiceTest {
            static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(OdValuesServiceTest.class.getName());

            @Autowired
            OdValuesService odValuesService;
            @Autowired
            DBCommonsService dbCommonsService;

@Commit       
@Test
            public void addOdValue() throws Exception {

                OdValuesEntity odValuesEntity = new OdValuesEntity();
                odValuesEntity.setId(dbCommonsService.getNextDocOD("OD_VALUES_ID_GEN"));
                odValuesEntity.setSysname("Name" + DataGenerator.getRandomISIN());
                odValuesEntity.setName("Name");
                odValuesEntity.setIsIn((short) 1);
                odValuesEntity.setvType(2);
                odValuesEntity.setMfu((short) 0);
                odValuesEntity.setIsin("AU000A0JP922");
                odValuesEntity.setCfi("");
               odValuesService.addOdValue(odValuesEntity);
          }
      }
```

Comment: code for `odValuesDAO.addOdValue(odValuesEntity);` plz

Comment: @Antoniossss, I added update to issue body. Thank you.

Comment: Remove the `@Bean` declarations for the `EntityManager` you must inject the entitymanager with `@PersistenceContext` and not with `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html):

> 15.2.3 Transaction management
>
> [..]By default, the framework will create and roll back a transaction
>   **for each test**.[..]

So, if your "problem" is, that no data is written to the database in your tests when using `@Transactional`, then that's no problem at all, it's how the spring default works. If that's not what you want...

> If you want a transaction to commit — unusual, but occasionally useful
>   when you want a particular test to populate or modify the
>   database — the TestContext framework can be instructed to cause the
>   transaction to commit instead of roll back via the [@Commit](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#integration-testing-annotations) annotation.

Comment: Florian, thank you. I added annotation `@Commit @Test` to the test method but data still not saved.

Comment: Your test isn't transactional so adding `@Commit` isn't going to do anything (only if your test was to be `@Transactional`).

Comment: I added `@Transactional` annotation to the `@Test` and have new exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: To use the default BatchConfigurer the context must contain no more than one DataSource, found 2`. Do i need to qualify Datasource beans or what to do?