# Data is not saved in DB when using Transaction annotation in JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, jpa, junit, transactions

Colleagues, I can not solve a problem with a transactions in Spring more than week. 
I have created quite similar post ([Why data wasn't saved when I use @Transactional annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39317601/why-data-wasnt-saved-when-i-use-transactional-annotation)), but could't to solve the problem in it; of course i took into account the recommendations who gave @Florian Schaetz. I kindly ask you to help me.

So, I have the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@Transactional

public class OdValuesServiceTest {
    static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(OdValuesServiceTest.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    OdValuesService odValuesService;
    @Autowired
    DBCommonsService dbCommonsService;

    @Transactional ("txManagerDU")
    @Test
    @Commit

    public void addOdValue() throws Exception {


                OdValuesEntity odValuesEntity = new OdValuesEntity();
                odValuesEntity.setId(dbCommonsService.getNextDocOD("OD_VALUES_ID_GEN"));
                odValuesEntity.setSysname("Name" + DataGenerator.getRandomISIN());
                odValuesEntity.setName("Name");
                odValuesEntity.setIsIn((short) 1);
                odValuesEntity.setvType(2);
                odValuesEntity.setMfu((short) 0);
                odValuesEntity.setIsin("AU000A0JP922");
                odValuesEntity.setCfi("");

                odValuesService.addOdValue(odValuesEntity);
    }
}
```

Interface class `addOdValue` looks like:

```
public interface OdValuesDAO {

    public void addOdValue (OdValuesEntity odValuesEntity);

}
```

And DAO implementation class is :

```
@Component
public class OdValuesDAOImpl implemets OdValuesDAO  
{

    static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(OdValuesDAO.class.getName());


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("emDU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void addOdValue (OdValuesEntity odValuesEntity) {
        LOG.info(odValuesEntity.toString());

        LOG.info("Transaction is active:" + em.getTransaction().isActive());
        //em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(odValuesEntity);
        //em.getTransaction().commit();

    }

}
```

Spring context, as config file, is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan

public class AppConfig {

static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AppConfig.class.getName());


/*There are some beans to work with properties file*/

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource primaryDuDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource primaryDuDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        primaryDuDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
        primaryDuDataSource.setUrl(primaryDuDbUrl);
        primaryDuDataSource.setUsername(primaryDuDbUser);
        primaryDuDataSource.setPassword(primaryDuDbPassword);
        primaryDuDataSource.setMaxIdle(30);
        primaryDuDataSource.setMaxWaitMillis(10000);

        primaryDuDataSource.setValidationQuery("select 1 from rdb$database");
        primaryDuDataSource.setTestOnBorrow(false);
        primaryDuDataSource.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        primaryDuDataSource.setDefaultAutoCommit(true);

        return primaryDuDataSource;
    }


    @Bean

    public BasicDataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource secondaryDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        secondaryDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        secondaryDataSource.setUrl(scndsysDbUrl);
        secondaryDataSource.setUsername(scndsysDbUser);
        secondaryDataSource.setPassword(scndsysDbPassword);
        secondaryDataSource.setMaxIdle(2);
        secondaryDataSource.setMaxWaitMillis(10000);
        secondaryDataSource.setValidationQuery("select 1");
        secondaryDataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        secondaryDataSource.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        secondaryDataSource.setDefaultAutoCommit(true);
        return secondaryDataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory (@Qualifier("secondaryDataSource") BasicDataSource secondaryDataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localConnectionFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        localConnectionFactoryBean.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml");
        localConnectionFactoryBean.setDataSource(secondaryDataSource);
        localConnectionFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        return localConnectionFactoryBean;
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryprmsys (@Qualifier("primaryDuDataSource")BasicDataSource primaryDuDataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml");
        emf.setDataSource(primaryDuDataSource);
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect");
        emf.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter);

        return emf;
    }


    @Bean
    public EntityManager emDU (@Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryprmsys") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryprmsys) {
        return entityManagerFactoryprmsys.createEntityManager();
    }


    @Bean
    public EntityManager emscndsys (@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory ) {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }




    @Bean
    public  JpaTransactionManager txManagerDU (@Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryprmsys") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryprmsys) {
         JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
         txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryprmsys);
         return txManager;
    }


    @Bean
    public  JpaTransactionManager txManagerscndsys (@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

Stacktrace is :

```
>     "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java" -ea
>     -Didea.launcher.port=7537 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3\bin"
>     -Didea.junit.sm_runner
>     -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "jars"
>     com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain
>     com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5
>     au.acap.app.JpaEntities.Service.OdValuesServiceTest,addOdValue
>     log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 86 and column 23 log4j:WARN The
>     content of element type "log4j:configuration" must match
>     "(renderer*,throwableRenderer?,appender*,plugin*,(category|logger)*,root?,(categoryFactory|loggerFactory)?)". INFO : [sep-16 15:08:48,172]
>     context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default
>     TestExecutionListener class names from location
>     [META-INF/spring.factories]:
>     [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener,
>     org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener,
>     org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener,
>     org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener,
>     org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener,
>     org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
>     INFO : [sep-16 15:08:48,213]
>     context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Could not instantiate
>     TestExecutionListener
>     [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener].
>     Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes
>     (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class:
>     [org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestAttributes] INFO :
>     [sep-16 15:08:48,215] context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper -
>     Using TestExecutionListeners:
>     [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@67784306,
>     org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@335eadca,
>     org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@210366b4,
>     org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@eec5a4a,
>     org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@2b2948e2]INFO
>     : [sep-16 15:08:48,402] context.support.GenericApplicationContext -
>     Refreshing
>     org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@3712b94:
>     startup date [Fri Sep 16 15:08:48 MSK 2016]; root of context hierarchy
>     INFO : [sep-16 15:08:48,956] app.Commons.QortCommons - StartDate:
>         24.06.2016 00:00:00 INFO : [sep-16 15:08:48,958] app.Commons.QortCommons - EndDate: 11.08.2016 23:59:59 INFO : [sep-16
>     15:08:48,970] acap.app.AppConfig -  mainClassLocation:
>     /C:/Users/maya/Documents/GIT/qort-integration/prmsys/target/classes/
>     INFO : [sep-16 15:08:48,971] acap.app.AppConfig - Properties will read
>     from:
>     /C:/Users/maya/Documents/GIT/qort-integration/prmsys/target/classes/application.properties
>     INFO : [sep-16 15:08:49,238]
>     orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA
>     container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'PersistenceUnit'
>     INFO : [sep-16 15:08:50,587]
>     orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA
>     container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'PersistenceUnit'
>     Hibernate: create table HT_OD_A_SHARES (SHARE integer not null,
>     hib_sess_id CHAR(36)) Hibernate: create table HT_OD_DOLS (ID integer
>     not null, hib_sess_id CHAR(36)) Hibernate: create table HT_OD_VALUES
>     (ID integer not null, hib_sess_id CHAR(36)) .... INFO : [sep-16
>     15:08:52,350] java.sql.DatabaseMetaData - HHH000262: Table not found:
>     ...... ERROR: [sep-16 15:08:52,442] tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate -
>     HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table ..... ERROR: [sep-16
>     15:08:52,444] tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - GDS Exception. 335544569.
>     Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 1, column
>     17 . ERROR: [sep-16 15:08:52,449] tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate -
>     HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table .....
>     INFO : [sep-16 15:08:52,741] context.transaction.TransactionContext - Began transaction (1) for
>     test context [DefaultTestContext@222afc67 testClass =
>     OdValuesServiceTest, testInstance =
>     au.acap.app.JpaEntities.Service.OdValuesServiceTest@4c2fb9dd,
>     testMethod = addOdValue@OdValuesServiceTest, testException = [null],
>     mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@58cf8f94
>     testClass = OdValuesServiceTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class
>     au.acap.app.AppConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]',
>     activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}',
>     propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader =
>     'org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader',
>     parent = [null]]]; transaction manager
>     [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@54f4a7f0]; rollback
>     [false] Hibernate: select gen_id(OD_VALUES_ID_GEN,1) as DOC_ID from
>     rdb$database INFO : [sep-16 15:08:52,872]
>     JpaEntities.Service.DBCommonsService - docId = 10465 INFO : [sep-16
>     15:08:52,931] app.DAO.OdValuesDAO -
>     au.acap.app.JpaEntities.OdValuesEntity@70c0a3d5[   id=10465  
>     sysname=NameJP3228600007   name=Name   vType=2   isin=AU000A0JP922  
>     mfu=0   isIn=1   cfi= ] INFO : [sep-16 15:08:52,933]
>     app.DAO.OdValuesDAO - Transaction is active:false Hibernate: insert
>     into OD_VALUES (B_DATE, BASE_VAL, CFI, IS_IN, ISIN, MFU, NAME,
>     SYSNAME, V_TYPE, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) INFO :
>     [sep-16 15:08:53,004] context.transaction.TransactionContext -
>     Committed transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@222afc67
>     testClass = OdValuesServiceTest, testInstance =
>     au.acap.app.JpaEntities.Service.OdValuesServiceTest@4c2fb9dd,
>     testMethod = addOdValue@OdValuesServiceTest, testException = [null],
>     mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@58cf8f94
>     testClass = OdValuesServiceTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class
>     au.acap.app.AppConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]',
>     activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}',
>     propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader =
>     'org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader',
>     parent = [null]]]. INFO : [sep-16 15:08:53,007]
>     context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Closing
>     org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@3712b94:
>     startup date [Fri Sep 16 15:08:48 MSK 2016]; root of context hierarchy
>     INFO : [sep-16 15:08:53,013]
>     orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA
>     EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'PersistenceUnit' INFO :
>     [sep-16 15:08:53,030] orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean -
>     Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'PersistenceUnit'
>     Process finished with exit code 0
```

The problem is that transaction is not commited. Please, help me to save data in DB during the test. Thank you.

**Update:**
Help still needed!

May be problem in my imports?

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;


import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
```

Comment: Log that you provided contains some errors

`ERROR: [sep-16 15:08:52,442] tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate -
>     HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table .....`

try to fix them first. 

Probably it can be fixed if you turn off `denerateDdl` option in your 'hibernateJpaVendorAdapter'.

Answer (score 4):

From the `@Commit` documentation:

> **Warning**: `@Commit` can be used as direct
>   replacement for `@Rollback(false)`; however, it should
>   **not** be declared alongside `@Rollback`. Declaring
>   `@Commit` and `@Rollback` on the same test method or on the
>   same test class is unsupported and may lead to unpredictable results."

So mixing `@Commit` and `@Rollback` is a bad idea.

Another thing that is the class/method `@Transactional` tag with different configuration (but I'm not sure if this is the problem here.)

Comment: I tried only @Commit annotation, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Spring didn't create the transaction for this

```
@Transactional (value = "txManagerDU", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void addOdValue (OdValuesEntity odValuesEntity) {
        odValuesDAO.addOdValue(odValuesEntity);
    }
```

Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW 
should create a new transaction independant of the other ones. But here it didn't do the job.

You should try to use Propagation.REQUIRED to see if there is a difference. The first transaction created for the test method is committed :

```
Committed transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@222afc67
testClass = OdValuesServiceTest, testInstance=
au.acap.app.JpaEntities.Service.OdValuesServiceTest@4c2fb9dd,
testMethod = addOdValue@OdValuesServiceTest
```

And avoid mixing     @Commit and     @Rollback too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I see this in your logs:

> ```
> ERROR: [sep-16 15:08:52,442] tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate -
> HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table ..... ERROR: [sep-16
> 15:08:52,444] tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - GDS Exception. 335544569.
> Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 1, column
> 17 . ERROR: [sep-16 15:08:52,449] tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate -
> HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table .....
> ```

I think you have your table already created that's why table creation is unsuccessful, so program fails to create table and that's why it can't execute (Error code is less than 0).

> ***[Edit]*** 
>   I also viewed your older question and agree with answer of [Tejas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2010052/tejas). I'd also suggest avoiding keyword as a table name.

Answer (score 0):

According to [SpringJunit4ClassRunner's documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-framework) you should better anotate your test like this :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="txManagerDU", defaultRollback=false)
@Transactional
public class OdValuesServiceTest {

    static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(OdValuesServiceTest.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    OdValuesService odValuesService;
    @Autowired
    DBCommonsService dbCommonsService;

    @Test
    public void addOdValue() throws Exception {
    ...
```

Comment: It doesn't help. Also `org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration' is deprecate`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just need to annotate `EntityManager` with `@PersistenceContext` annotation like:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("em")
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "PersistenceUnit", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
private EntityManager entityManager;
```